# Read, Write, Append, Delete Memory Mapped File

Tags: c#, memory-mapped-files

In my windows app, I want to use memory mapped files. There is various article/blogs on net that has enough information for creating memory mapped files. I am creating 2 memory mapped file and now I want to do some actions on these files like reading its content, append some content into it, delete some content from it. There may be more info on net for all these, but unfortunately I couldn't find anything. 
Below is the function I am using to write a memory mapped file.

```
 // Stores the path to the selected folder in the memory mapped file
        public void CreateMMFFile(string folderName, MemoryMappedFile mmf, string fileName)
        {
            // Lock
            bool mutexCreated;
            Mutex mutex = new Mutex(true, fileName, out mutexCreated);
            try
            {
                using (MemoryMappedViewStream stream = mmf.CreateViewStream())
                {
                    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream, System.Text.Encoding.Unicode))
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(folderName, "*.*", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories);
                            foreach (string str in files)
                            {
                                writer.WriteLine(str);
                            }
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            Debug.WriteLine("Unable to write string. " + ex);
                        }
                        finally
                        {
                            mutex.ReleaseMutex();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Unable to monitor memory file. " + ex);
            }
        }
```

If anyone can help me, that would be really appreciated.

Comment: What part of the [MSDN documentation examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997372.aspx) are you specifically having a problem understanding?

Comment: I didn't say anything like that. Down vote?? Reason??

Comment: The documentation (and specifically the example in the documentation) contains example of reading and writing from/to a MMF so I'm confused then; what are you asking?

Comment: oops sorry, I didn't see that.

Comment: It's at the bottom of the page I did link.

Comment: I didn't. I actually enjoyed your question.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8381/discussion-between-deepak-and-m-babcock)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the class you're looking for is the [`MemoryMappedViewAccessor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorymappedfiles.memorymappedviewaccessor.aspx). It provides methods for reading and writing to your memory-mapped file. A delete is nothing more than a series of carefully orchestrated writes.

It can be created from your `MemoryMappedFile` class using the [`CreateViewAccessor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267554.aspx) method.

Answer (score 0):

In this code I did something similar to what you want to implement. I write to the MMF every second, you can have other process reading the content from that file:

```
var data = new SharedData
{
    Id = 1,
    Value = 0
};

var mutex = new Mutex(false, "MmfMutex");

using (var mmf = MemoryMappedFile.CreateOrOpen("MyMMF", Marshal.SizeOf(data)))
{
     using (var accessor = mmf.CreateViewAccessor())
     {
          while (true)
          {
              mutex.WaitOne();
              accessor.Write(0, ref data);
              mutex.ReleaseMutex();

              Console.WriteLine($"Updated Value to: {data.Value}");
              data.Value++;
              Thread.Sleep(1000);
           }
     }
}
```

Take a look to [this article](https://csharpvault.com/blog/memory-mapped-files/), to understand how you can share data between processes using MMF.